# Issues loading an epub using FolioReaderKit

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to load an epub using Folio Reader Kit.

I have the following code in swift

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.incrementReads()

            self.working = true;

            let config = FolioReaderConfig()
            config.scrollDirection = .vertical
            config.hideBars = false
            config.allowSharing = false
            config.enableTTS = false
            config.tintColor = UIColor(red: 132/255.0, green: 203/255.0, blue: 213/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            config.menuTextColor = UIColor(red: 132/255.0, green: 203/255.0, blue: 213/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            config.shouldHideNavigationOnTap = false

            let folioReader = FolioReader()
            NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationStarted()
            LoadingIndicatorView.show("Loading")

            if let readUrl = URL(string: self.data.epub) {
                Downloader.load(audioUrl: readUrl, completion: { (destinationUrl) in
                    print(destinationUrl)
                    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()
                    LoadingIndicatorView.hide()
                    self.working = false;

                    folioReader.presentReader(parentViewController: self, withEpubPath: destinationUrl.path, andConfig: config)
                });
            }
        }
```

The code throws an error when it tries to call presentReader.

What happens is that the code downloads the epub from the internet, saves it to the computer/iphone, and tries to present it to the reader. It used to work before, but even though I have not made any changes to that part of the code, it now throws an error. Can someone please help?

Here's the code for the Downloader.swift

```
class Downloader {
    class func load(audioUrl: URL, completion: @escaping (URL) -> Void) {
        // then lets create your document folder url
        let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

        // lets create your destination file url
        let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)

        // to check if it exists before downloading it
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path) {
            completion(destinationUrl)
        } else {

            // you can use NSURLSession.sharedSession to download the data asynchronously
            URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: audioUrl, completionHandler: { (location, response, error) -> Void in
                guard let location = location, error == nil else { return }
                do {
                    // after downloading your file you need to move it to your destination url
                    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationUrl)

                    completion(destinationUrl)

                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing similar issue, if you have solved this, please share answer.

Comment: @Vibhs Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You're using DispatchQueue.main.async in a wrong place as I see.
Your download method returns callback on non-main queue, but working with UI should always happen on main.

It seems that you should dispatch your rendering code to the main queue like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    folioReader.presentReader(parentViewController: self, withEpubPath: destinationUrl.path, andConfig: config)
}
```